# Binomial probability distribution exercise

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am learning probability and found an exercise I could not get:

> An investment analyst has tracked a certain blue-chip stock for the past six months and found that  on any given day it either goes up a point or down a point. Furthermore, it went up on 25% of the days and down on $75\%.$
>
> What is the probability that at the close of trading four days from now the price of the stock will be the same as it is today? Assume that the daily fluctuations are independent events.

The answer is $0.211,$ but I just tried to order the pieces, and found that based on the six months that is $180$ days and based on the $25\%$ of days going up and $75\%$ going down, that is $45$ and $135$ days.

So if $n$ is $180$ and $k$ is $45$ and $135,$ what is $p?$

How can I operate: ${n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}.$ Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, you need two up days and two down, so $\binom 42 \times \left( \frac 14 \right)^2 \times  \left( \frac 34 \right)^2\approx 0.2109375$.

Comment: Note:  I have no idea what all the stuff about the exact number of days in the history has to do with anything.  Physically sensible or not, we are assuming a binomial process with $p=\frac 14$ and it's easy to calculate how that, stripped down, process plays out.

Comment: Thanks lulu. Great about those 180 days that has nothing to do in the case! But I do not understand something: Why k is 2? Which formula did you use? Thanks.

Comment: You have four moves, each of which is either $\pm 1$.  The only way these can sum to $0$ is if you had two $1's$ and two $-1's$.

Comment: I got it! thanks!